# Why is setting minChunks in Webpack 4 breaking the build for the cacheGroup?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

The size of my built chunks are too large so I'm trying to break them into smaller chunks. When I set the `minChunks` [condition](https://gist.github.com/sokra/1522d586b8e5c0f5072d7565c2bee693#conditions) on a `cacheGroup` it prevents that group from building, with no errors provided. What am I doing wrong in my config?

```
// webpack.common.js

entry: {
    build: path.join(setPath('src'), 'main.js')
},
output: {
    path: setPath('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[hash:8].js'
},
```

### Without `minChunks`

```
// webpack.prod.js

optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      vendors: {
        test: /node_modules/,
        chunks: 'all'
      }
    }
  }
}

// output
                       Asset     Size      Chunks                  Chunk Names
js/vendors~build.2ef9f7c1.js     1.98 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendors~build
js/build.2ef9f7c1.js             354 KiB        1  [emitted]  [big]  build
index.html                       592 bytes         [emitted]
```

### With `minChunks`

```
// webpack.prod.js

optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      vendors: {
        test: /node_modules/,
        chunks: 'all',
        minChunks: 2
      }
    }
  }
}

// output
               Asset            Size       Chunks                  Chunk Names
js/build.77d425d4.js            2.33 MiB        0  [emitted]  [big]  build
index.html                      454 bytes          [emitted]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change minChunks from 2 to 1, it will work fine. Because you only have one entry file named "build" which is the only chunk sharing the common dependencies.